How can I access a site with two-form factor using python requests?
My problem right now is i'm trying to write a program to download log files from a URL that requires authentication with two-form factor.  For obvious reasons i'm not going to give the actual URL, but for example i'm trying to access URL "https://www.logsite.com/flashlogfile" using the following code.
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

dir = 'C:/Logs'     #   Only an example since this will be input by the user.
fileName = 'file.txt'  #  Only an example since this will be input by the user.

url = "https://www.logsite.com/flashlogfile"

user = 'user'
pwd = 'pwd'

auth = HTTPBasicAuth(user,pwd)

resp = requests.get(url,auth=auth)

with open(f'{dir}/{fileName}.txt','wb') as file:
    file.write(chunk)


All I'm getting from this is the HTML of the webpage and not the file itself.  I'm very new to this so any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

So if you hit the endpoint in a browser while authenticated, you get the log file but formatted with HTML? There might be a “raw” endpoint, try hitting that instead. I don’t know enough about the service you are interacting with to be able to help with that end. If you can only get HTML you are going to have to parse the HTML.
